# MVC Route with an area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In MVC 5, I have an old controller "MyOld" and need it to point to "MyNew", but the request keeps going to MyOld.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "newthing",
           url: "Trade/MyOld",
           defaults: new { controller = "MyNew", action = "Index", area = "Trade" }
           ).DataTokens.Add("area","Trade");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add Router to method `RegisterArea`:

**TradeAreaRegistration.cs**

```
public class TradeAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Trade";
            }
        }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {    
        context.MapRoute(
         name: "MyOldToMyNew",
         url: "Trade/MyOld",
         defaults: new { controller = "MyNew", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );

        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Trade_default",
            url: "Trade/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```